# C# dynamic update of control created in a dll

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, controls

I created a Control and compiled it into a DLL:

```
namespace TSControlLibrary
{
    public partial class BaseMaskedTextBox : MaskedTextBox
    {
        public BaseMaskedTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BackColor = Color.Pink;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created another Test project and want to use this new MaskedTextBox on it...

Which pretty much works,

1 - I added the reference to the DLL in Test.  And kept the default properties.  Copy Local = True, Specific Version = False

2 - I added the DLL to the toolbox, which shows the BaseMaskedTextBox.

Now I can add a new masked thingy onto my winform.  :-)

BUT!!!  But when I want to change the original DLL from Color.Pink to Color.Blue it will allow me to add a new MaskedTextBox on the form in Blue.  But the Pink is still Pink.

What I would like to do is change the DLL color, recompile that and the new Test project will have the new color.  How can I do this?

VS2012, winforms, heh.

Comment: have you considered exposing a background property on your control?  no recompile needed.

Comment: the color change is just so I can see it change the control, I plan on having a few other things change, probably never the color when I am done...  Font Size, methods, validations...

Comment: Have you tried incrementing the [`AssemblyVersion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k49w9389(v=vs.110).aspx) number ?

Comment: Turns out the DLL is getting updated and actually setting the color, but the Test.Designer.cs just resets it back.  So its not the DLL...  :-)  Also the designer will set the colors ( and some other things ) before going into design mode - so maybe this is getting a bit silly.  Know of any event that fires after the designer loads and before its shown on the designer screen?

Comment: locationChanged event fires at the right time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm...  well, it looks like I figured it out.  :-)

I found that the DLL color set works, it updates the color from the default to Green or whatever, but then the Test.Designer.cs runs after that and just resets it to whatever it was when I added it hours ago.

So after a while on my Test form I have 30 different boxes all different colors.  Because the designer.cs keeps track of where they go and some other things - like colors and font size and things.

So, I found that LocationChanged event will fire after the designer, but before it shows on the screen.  So that was the ticket.

```
   public BaseMaskedTextBoxDate2()
    {
        this.LocationChanged += new EventHandler(Setup);
    }


    //*************************************************************************************************
    private void Setup(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MaskedTextBox maskedBox = (MaskedTextBox)sender;

        maskedBox.BackColor = Color.Gray;  // For testing and also to make sure all fields are handled.
        maskedBox.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10.0f);
        maskedBox.ValidatingType = typeof(System.DateTime);
        maskedBox.BeepOnError = false;
        maskedBox.TypeValidationCompleted += new TypeValidationEventHandler(maskedTextBoxDate_TypeValidationCompleted);
        ...
    }
```

Now, if I have the DLL version ( above ) open in an instance of VS and make a change, say to the font size, going from 10 to 20, on the other instance of VS that is Test it will update on the Test Design View instantly - and with 20 font it will also be pretty nasty looking...  And when compiled it will also be correct - as shown in Design.

Oddly, the only thing that I can't change is the Mask.  But I doubt I will ever change that from 00/00/0000 - at least for this project anyway.

Comment: lol, and it turns out I do want to change the mask for a currency version...  lol...  ahh, never say never I guess.